# Laravel 5.5 Internal server error on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5

I have moved my laravel 5.5 files to Ubuntu `var/www/html` folder

For some reasons I'm getting and internal server error (500).

I have changed permissions of the `storage` folder but this doesn't work.

- Laravel 5.5
- Ubuntu
- Amazon ec2

Comment: Where is your project being hosted (DigitalOcean?). Are you using nginx?

Comment: its on amazon ec2

Comment: You have to set write permission on bootstrap/cache folder also. So that web server can write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride
```

Change to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Restart Your server

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: its already there.

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/public">
 Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
 AllowOverride All
 #Order allow,deny 
 Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: have you change file permission

Comment: No can you tell me exactly which file ? i have changed permissions for storage folder

Comment: chmod 777 /var/www/html/public chmod 777 /var/www/html chmod 777 /var/www/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/920674/how-do-i-change-group-ownership-on-folders-created-by-a-specific-user

Comment: grand the permission to single user chown

Comment: not to to whole dir change permission only (var/www/html)

Comment: Please do NOT EVER set the permissions to 777! This is very bad practice and a big security issue! And also, please do not ever advise anyone to do so, there are usually better and more restrictive permissions usable.  Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/1863487